# Number of flushes in a deck of cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics, poker

I am having trouble finding the number of flushes in a deck of 52 cards. My logic is that you have 52 choices for the first card, 12 choices for the second, 11 for the third, etc. The number of flushes should thus be equal to:

$$52 \cdot 12 \cdot 11 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 = 617760$$

How is this logic incorrect?

Comment: $4$ suits ${13\choose 5}$ ways to pick the numbers. $4\cdot{13\choose 5}.$  The problem with your logic, you have A,K,10, 7, 3 of hearts as a different hand from 3,7,A,K, 10

Comment: Oh makes sense, I forgot that order doesn't matter. Thanks!

Comment: Why not post as answer?

Comment: Are you assuming that five cards are drawn from the deck?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in a comment that number is permutations not combinations.

$\binom{4}{1} \binom{13}{5} = 5148$

$\frac {52*12*11*10*9} {5!} = 5148$